# Spark : Complex count aggregation with joins for scattered dates on different columns in Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a input dataframe wherein each row has a unique GUID and belongs to a group. Each row has different "Date" columns (in reality, there are 15 date columns). Note that the date values are randomly scattered across date columns.

```
val df= Seq(
("GUID11",  "Grp1",     1,      "01-01-2023",       None),
("GUID12",  "Grp2",     1,      "01-01-2023",       Some("01-01-2023")),
("GUID21",  "Grp1",     2,      "01-02-2023",       Some("01-01-2023")),
("GUID22",  "Grp1",     2,      "01-02-2023",       Some("01-02-2023")),
("GUID23",  "Grp1",     2,      "01-02-2023",       None),
("GUID31",  "Grp2",     3,      "01-03-2023",       Some("01-03-2023")),
("GUID32",  "Grp1",     3,      "01-03-2023",       Some("01-04-2023")),
("GUID41",  "Grp1",     4,      "01-04-2023",       Some("01-04-2023")),
("GUID42",  "Grp1",     4,      "01-04-2023",       Some("01-04-2023")),
("GUID44",  "Grp3",     4,      "01-04-2023",       None),
("GUID45",  "Grp1",     4,      "01-04-2023",       Some("01-04-2023")),
("GUID51",  "Grp1",     5,      "01-05-2023",       Some("01-05-2023")),
("GUID61",  "Grp2",     6,      "01-06-2023",       Some("01-06-2023")),
("GUID62",  "Grp1",     6,      "01-06-2023",       None),
("GUID63",  "Grp3",     6,      "01-06-2023",       Some("01-06-2023")),
("GUID64",  "Grp3",     6,      "01-06-2023",       Some("01-06-2023")),
("GUID65",  "Grp1",     6,      "01-06-2023",       Some("01-06-2023"))
).toDF("GUID", "Group", "Occurence","Date1","Date2")
```

It looks as following :

```
+------+-----+---------+----------+----------+
|  GUID|Group|Occurence|     Date1|     Date2|
+------+-----+---------+----------+----------+
|GUID11| Grp1|        1|2023-01-01|      null|
|GUID12| Grp2|        1|2023-01-01|2023-01-01|
|GUID21| Grp1|        2|2023-01-02|2023-01-01|
|GUID22| Grp1|        2|2023-01-02|2023-01-02|
|GUID23| Grp1|        2|2023-01-02|      null|
|GUID31| Grp2|        3|2023-01-03|2023-01-03|
|GUID32| Grp1|        3|2023-01-03|2023-01-04|
|GUID41| Grp1|        4|2023-01-04|2023-01-04|
|GUID42| Grp1|        4|2023-01-04|2023-01-04|
|GUID44| Grp3|        4|2023-01-04|      null|
|GUID45| Grp1|        4|2023-01-04|2023-01-04|
|GUID51| Grp1|        5|2023-01-05|2023-01-05|
|GUID61| Grp2|        6|2023-01-06|2023-01-06|
|GUID62| Grp1|        6|2023-01-06|      null|
|GUID63| Grp3|        6|2023-01-06|2023-01-06|
|GUID64| Grp3|        6|2023-01-06|2023-01-06|
|GUID65| Grp1|        6|2023-01-06|2023-01-06|
+------+-----+---------+----------+----------+
```

The requirement is to get unique count of dates (for different 'Date' columns) for each group.
So the required output looks something like this:

```
Correct Result:
+-----+----------+------+------+
|Group|      Date|Count1|Count2|
+-----+----------+------+------+
| Grp1|2023-01-01|     1|     1|
| Grp2|2023-01-01|     1|     1|
| Grp1|2023-01-02|     3|     1|
| Grp1|2023-01-03|     1|  null|
| Grp2|2023-01-03|     1|     1|
| Grp1|2023-01-04|     3|     4|
| Grp3|2023-01-04|     1|  null|
| Grp1|2023-01-05|     1|     1|
| Grp1|2023-01-06|     2|     1|
| Grp2|2023-01-06|     1|     1|
| Grp3|2023-01-06|     2|     2|
+-----+----------+------+------+
```

I got a working solution for this simple example as follows :

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("Date1", to_date($"Date1","MM-dd-yyyy"))
            .withColumn("Date2", to_date($"Date2","MM-dd-yyyy"))

val df2 = df1.groupBy("Group","Date1").agg(count("Occurence").as("Count1")).filter($"Date1".isNotNull)
.withColumnRenamed("Date1","Date")

val df3 = df1.groupBy("Group","Date2").agg(count("Occurence").as("Count2")).filter($"Date2".isNotNull)
.withColumnRenamed("Date2","Date")

val df4 = df2.join(df3, Seq("Group","Date"), "outer").orderBy("Date", "Group")
println("Correct Result:")
df4.show
```

The problem with this solution is, it can be quite expensive, since the above steps need to be done on all 15 date columns and the dataframe is quite large.

Is there is any simpler / more efficient solution to get the required output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add genetic columns; one for the `Date` and another one for `Name` and then use `array`, `arrays_zip` with `explode` to spread out the values on multiple rows

```scala
df.withColumn("AllDates", array($"Date1", $"Date2"))
    .withColumn("AllDateNames", array(lit("Count1"), lit("Count2")))
    .withColumn("DatesNames", arrays_zip($"AllDates", $"AllDateNames"))
    .withColumn("DateName", explode($"DatesNames"))
    .withColumn("Date", $"DateName.AllDates")
    .withColumn("Name", $"DateName.AllDateNames")
    .filter($"Date".isNotNull)
    .groupBy("Group", "Date")
    .pivot("Name")
    .count()
    .show()
```

```
+-----+----------+------+------+
|Group|      Date|Count1|Count2|
+-----+----------+------+------+
| Grp1|01-01-2023|     1|     1|
| Grp3|01-04-2023|     1|  null|
| Grp1|01-05-2023|     1|     1|
| Grp3|01-06-2023|     2|     2|
| Grp1|01-03-2023|     1|  null|
| Grp1|01-06-2023|     2|     1|
| Grp2|01-03-2023|     1|     1|
| Grp1|01-04-2023|     3|     4|
| Grp2|01-06-2023|     1|     1|
| Grp1|01-02-2023|     3|     1|
| Grp2|01-01-2023|     1|     1|
+-----+----------+------+------+
```

Comment: Theoretically answer looks correct! Can you pls convert Name & Count to Count1 and Count2?

Comment: @Ganesha In this case you need to add `pivot`. Answer updated!

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I am pretty sure this is much more efficient than joins :-)

Comment: I have another challenge now :-) There is a count column which has distinct counts on "Occurrence" column along with normal count for "Count1" and "Count2". In this case, the above solution with general group and count will not work, right?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but I think if it is just to sum this count per group, date-col you can just add `.sum("count")` after the `pivot`